# How can I create an event in Microsoft Outlook web interface so that attendees may edit the event?

Tags: outlook.com, outlook.com-calendar

How can I create an event in Microsoft Outlook web interface so that attendees may edit the event?

E.g., in Google Calendar, I can choose:

[image]